# How to copy media (videos) from app sandbox storage to DCIM dir

Tags: android-studio

I am downloading videos from my server in the application sandbox storage, at this path:

```
final String filePath = this.getExternalFilesDir("videos") + "/" + name + ".mp4";
```

Now, I want to copy some specific files from the path above to another folder in DCIM so users can discover the videos in the gallery.

I am able to create that file, but I don't understand how to copy and move the file.

```
 File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "MyFolder");
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            boolean rv = dir.mkdir();
            Log.d(TAG, "Folder creation " + ( rv ? "success" : "failed"));
        }
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using standard Java IO stream.

```
String inputFile = "/" + name + ".mp4";
String inputPath = this.getExternalFilesDir("videos") + "";
String outputPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "MyFolder") + "";

private void copyFile(String inputFile, String inputPath, String outputPath) {
    try {
        File dir = new File(outputPath);
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            if (!dir.mkdirs()) {
                return;
            }
        }

        try (InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputPath + inputFile)) {
            try (OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputPath + inputFile)) {
                File source = new File(inputPath + inputFile);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int read;

                long length = source.length();
                long total = 0;

                while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    total += read;

                    int progress = (int) ((total * 100) / length);
                    if (progress == 100) {
                        Toast.makeText(VideoActivity.this, "Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e);
    }
}
```